# Excel finding the code for a cell to be equal or more than another cell to give 1- 5 points

Tags: google-sheets

Google Spreadsheet on google drive. I have just made a survey on google drive for people to fill in their football predictions for fun! I can put all of the publics predictions into an excel document in one click but I want the public to earn points when they predict the right result. For example if a friend of mine predicted Arsenal 2 - 1 Liverpool and the result is Arsenal 1 - 0 Liverpool they should earn 1 point for predicting the right winner and if the prediction was equal to Arsenal 2 - 1 Liverpool, the prediction should earn 3 points.

I am struggling with the code for it but here is the closest I have got:

```
COUNTIF(F5, ʺ>=ʺ & E5)
```

The code above does not work and I cannot figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated as soon as possible. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that this is not an answer, but I am unable to comment without higher reputation.  It would be helpful to have access to a copy or example of what you have, as your cell references mean very little without.  Then we can see exactly what you have tried.

EDIT::

Without knowing how your sheet works or is laid out, it is difficult, however I've put this together for you on Google Sheets here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Ejaddmj2d8cysxdZE_Inro65KDFgzeJW7FqPWwaCpE/edit?usp=sharing

It's a very clunky set of nested IF statements but it does work.  I'm sure there is a neater way of doing it.

In case you can't view it, here is the formula

```
=IF(A2>B2, IF(D2>E2, IF(A2=D2, IF(B2=E2,"3","1"),"1"),"0"), IF(A2=B2, IF(D2=E2, IF(A2=D2, IF(B2=E2,"3","1"),"1"),"0"), IF(D2<E2, IF(A2=D2, IF(B2=E2,"3","1"),"1"),"0")))
```

In this case, A2 is Arsenal's score, B2 is Liverpool's score, D2 is Fred's Arsenal score prediction and E2 is his Liverpool prediction.  I placed the above formula in cell F2 to give Fred's points.

The above code first checks to see

- if Arsenal beat Liverpool, if true it then checks
- if Fred predicted that Arsenal would beat Liverpool.  If true, then it checks
- if Fred got Arsenal's score correct.  If true, it checks
- if Fred got Liverpool's score correct. If that's true,

then Fred got everything right and gets 3 points (and a cookie =]).

If Fred gets the winner right but not the scores, he gets 1 point. Otherwise he gets 0.

This formula also checks to see if Liverpool beat Arsenal and runs the same checks against Fred's prediction, then to see if the teams drew and to see if Fred predicted a draw or not.  If he predicts a draw and the correct scores he gets 3 points, otherwise he gets 1 for getting the draw correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you are looking for .. attached are a formula and result view of my answer ;)

[formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWU6v.png)

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NLuW.png)